# How to make devices appear in "Add Device" wizard in windows?

Tags: windows, drivers

In the toaster example, windows drivers sample, the KMDF bus driver notifies PnP manager about new device arrival by calling IoInvalidateDeviceRelations() and then PnP manager adds the device to "Devices and Printers". Is it possible to add those devices to "Add Device" wizard as well? and if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: What is the "add device" wizard... I think you need to preinstall the driver, did you try devcon or pnputil?